# Передача битмапа в функцию как параметр

Tags: c#

Есть метод получения цвета пикселя(на Picturebox):

```
private Color Look(Bitmap bp)
        {            
            if (y - 1 < 0 || y + 1 > bp.Height || x - 1 < 0 || x + 1 > bp.Width)
                return Color.Aquamarine;
            return bp.GetPixel(x, y);
        }
```

Есть определённый объект Bitmap:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            map = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            g = Graphics.FromImage(map);
        }

        Bitmap map;
        Graphics g;
```

Когда я передаю map в метод, он не работает. У меня вопрос: надо ли что-то делать в методе с параметром типа Bitmap, чтобы можно было вызывать метод GetPixel? Или дело не в этом?

Ред.
К примеру, делаем метод Look публичным и пишем так:

```
if (radioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    g = Graphics.FromImage(map);
                    Karp TKarp = new Karp(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), //определяем объект
                        Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text),
                        Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text),
                        Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text),
                        domainUpDown1.Text, g);
                    Taquarium.AddKarp(TKarp);
                    pictureBox1.Image = map;
                    if (TKarp.Look(map).ToArgb() == Color.Aquamarine.ToArgb()) //считываем цвет пикселя, передавая map в метод
                    {
                        map.SetPixel(50, 50, Color.Red);
                    }
                }
```

Теперь то же самое, только вместо Look метод GetPixel:

```
if (radioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    g = Graphics.FromImage(map);
                    Karp TKarp = new Karp(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text),
                        Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text),
                        Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text),
                        Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text),
                        domainUpDown1.Text, g);
                    Taquarium.AddKarp(TKarp);
                    pictureBox1.Image = map;
                    if (map.GetPixel(50, 50).ToArgb() == Color.Aquamarine.ToArgb())  
                    {
                        map.SetPixel(50, 50, Color.Red);
                    }
                }
```

Во втором случае работает, в первом-нет

Ред.

```
public virtual void Run(LinkedList<Karp> karps, Graphics g, Bitmap bp)
        {
            switch (dir)
                {
                case "Вверх":
                    y -= speed;
                    break;
                case "Вниз":
                    y += speed;
                    break;
                case "Влево":
                    x -= speed;
                    break;
                case "Вправо":
                    x += speed;
                    break;
                }
            if (Look(bp).ToArgb() == Color.Gray.ToArgb()) SureChangeDir();
            else if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > Width || y > Length) SureChangeDir();
            else ChangeDir();
            Draw(g);
        }
```

Есть рыба, которая плавает. В зависимости от направления движения изменяется определённая координата. Сначала проверяется наличие скалы(нарисована серым цветом). Если рыба её достигла, она разворачивается. И только затем уже проверяется выход за границы picturebox(Width и Length). У меня, к примеру, скала есть в координатах (500,300), а размеры picturebox 600х400. ChangeDir просто рандомно меняет направление движения в любой момент времени(может не менять), отношения к проблеме он не имеет. Ну и затем рисуется рыба на новых координатах.

Ред.В метод передаётся чёрное изображение. Проверил так: создал переменную и присвоил ей значение метода Look, отладчик показал значение 00000000. А что надо сделать, чтобы метод работал с отрисованным изображением(метод находится в отдельном классе)? Пробовал передавать объект Image, но безрезультатно.

Comment: А что не работает то?

Comment: в приведенном коде `map` не передается в `Look`. Почему ты думаешь, что _он не работает_?

Comment: Как именно "не работает"? Как вы вызываете метод `Look`, что ему передаёте как параметр?

Comment: В общем, приведите больше релевантного кода и больше подробностей.

Comment: Хорошо, что дали больше кода. Но вы не ответили на вопрос: что значит "не работает"??? Не компилируется? Выдаёт ошибку (какую)? Выдаёт не тот результат? ЧТО ИМЕННО ПРОИСХОДИТ???

Comment: И да, хорошо бы посмотреть, чему равны `x` и `y` когда что-то "не работает", может до `GetPixel` просто не доходит ход вообще. И ещё вы явно считаете, что они начинаются с 1, а мне кажется это не так, координаты должно от 0 считаться, соответственно все проверки нужно на 1 сдвинуть вниз.

Comment: Ну должен же перекраситься пиксель, если выполняется условие

Comment: Сейчас тогда напишу метод, в котором используется Look

Comment: Из какого цвета в какой должен перекраситься?

Comment: Изначально он Аквамариновый, должен стать красным

Comment: Это действие просто для теста, практической пользы нет от этого перекрашивания

Comment: В общем, попробуйте либо пройти в отладке, либо отладочной печати везде понапихайте. Я не вижу таких явных проблем, возможно, дело вообще в чём-то другом.

Comment: Я задал переменную и присвоил ей значение метода Look. Отладчик показал значение {0;0;0;0}(чёрный цвет), хотя должен быть аквамариновый

Comment: Вы в отладчике посмотрите всё - чему равны переменные, какая ветка выполнилась и т.д.

Comment: Ну я в методе Run после switch написал var a=Look(bp) и поставил точку останова. Пишет {Name=0,ARGB=(0,0,0,0)}. Других переменных нет вроде

Comment: Внутри самого Look точку поставьте и там смотрите какие переменные и что происходит

Comment: Ну координата только одна меняется в зависимости от скорости и направления движения